# Parsing a JSON file(stored locally) and thus creating an array of objects in swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, parsing

i am a beginner to the json parsing terminology. i am actually trying to fetch data from a json file that is stored locally in my swift project. i have done all the things correct and can fetch data presently. But, i am unable to create an array of objects(objects will be created based on the set of values coming from the json file) . and then use that array in a  view controller(CompanyViewController.swift) class. i have written my json parsing code in a different class(CompanyHandler.swift here..) and all the fields have been initialized in another swift class(Company.swift here..).

My CompanyViewController.swift controller file is as following:

```
class CompanyViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    @IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var customCollectionViewCell = CustomCollectionViewCell()

        collectionView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "CustomCollectionViewCell", bundle:nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CustomCollectionViewCell")
        collectionView!.multipleTouchEnabled = true
        collectionView!.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        self.view.addSubview(collectionView!)
        AppEngine().getCompanyDetails()

    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        var cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as CustomCollectionViewCell
//        cell.customImageView?.image = UIImage(named: "\(array[indexPath.row])")
        AppEngine().getCompanyDetails()

//        if ((cell.selected) && (indexPath.row == 0)) {
//        var vc: AbcViewController = AbcViewController(nibName: "AbcViewController", bundle: nil)
//        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
//        }
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
        var abc = CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.size.width,height: collectionView.frame.size.height/2)
        return abc
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldHighlightItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 15
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldShowMenuForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("CustomCollectionViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as CustomCollectionViewCell

        cell.customImageView?.image = UIImage(named: "image1.png")
        cell.customLabel?.text = "\(indexPath.row)"
        return cell
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}


My Company.swift controller file is as following:

class Company {
    var companyID: String
    var companyName: String
    var companyAddress: String
    var companyWebAddress: String
    var companyFB_Address: String
    var companyTWT_Handle: String
    var companyLI_Address: String
    var aboutUs: String
    var email_ID: String
    var ivrNo: String
//    var projects: NSMutableArray = ["Project"]
//    var projectStatus: String

    init(companyID: String, companyName: String,companyAddress: String, companyWebAddress: String, companyFB_Address: String, companyTWT_Handle: String, companyLI_Address: String, aboutUs: String, email_ID: String, ivrNo: String)
    {
        self.companyID = companyID
        self.companyName = companyName
        self.companyAddress = companyAddress
        self.companyWebAddress = companyWebAddress
        self.companyFB_Address = companyFB_Address
        self.companyTWT_Handle = companyTWT_Handle
        self.companyLI_Address = companyLI_Address
        self.aboutUs = aboutUs
        self.email_ID = email_ID
        self.ivrNo = ivrNo
//        self.projects = projects
//        self.projectStatus = projectStatus
    }
}



My CompanyHandler.swift controller file is as following:

class CompanyHandler {

// MARK: - company details
    func getCompanyDetails() {



 var jsonPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("companyDetails", ofType: "json")
        var data = NSData(contentsOfFile: jsonPath!)
        var jsonData: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!,
            options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSDictionary

        var companyArray:NSArray = jsonData["companyDetails"] as NSArray!

        for i in companyArray{
            var cmpID: String = i["companyID"] as String
            var cmpName: String = i["companyName"] as String
            var cmpAdd: String = i["companyAddress"] as String
            var cmpWebAdd: String = i["companyWebAddress"] as String
            var cmpfbAdd: String = i["companyFB_Address"] as String
            var cmptwtAdd: String = i["companyTWT_Handle"] as String
            var cmpliAdd: String = i["companyLI_Address"] as String
            var abtUs: String = i["aboutUs"] as String
            var emailId: String = i["email_ID"] as String
            var ivrNo: String = i["ivrNo"] as String
            println("\(ivrNo)")

        var company = Company(companyID: "cmpID", companyName: "cmpName", companyAddress: "cmpAdd", companyWebAddress: "cmpWebAdd", companyFB_Address: "cmpfbAdd", companyTWT_Handle: "cmptwtAdd", companyLI_Address: "cmpliAdd", aboutUs: "abtUs", email_ID: "emailId", ivrNo: "ivrNo")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: any suggestion is welcom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not actually creating an array of Company objects, which would act as your Data Source for your collection view.  You're just initializing new Company objects but not doing anything with them.  Create a property on your `CompanyViewController` and make it of type `[Company]`.  In each iteration through your json dictionaries, after you create a new Company, append it to your  array of `Company`'s, then use that array for your collection view.

Comment: actually i am unable to create an object and throw it to the array in ComapanyViewController class. also i am unable to append the  objects using the syntax             
var cmpID: AnyObject? = companyArray.objectAtIndex(i).objectForKey("companyID") as NSString

Comment: need to return an array from this function